# Decimal Size for fonts not working in Jasper Reports

Tags: styles, jasper-reports, font-size

I wonder why decimal sized fonts do not work with Jasper.
It gives validation error while using decimal font directly from iReport.
Using it via Style doesn't work.

I tried using `<style size='6.5'>This is my sample text</style>`, but in vain.
Do we have any work around for this?
Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Koushik

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. If you have found a solution, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is a problem of iReport only.

Actually Jasper uses `Integer.parseInt()` to parse the font size when compiling a template. So I guess using a decimal font size simple is not supported.